# Error:(30) Error parsing XML: mismatched tag

Tags: android

This is the first time I'm coding on Android Studio and I'm very new to programming. I'm getting an error in closing the LinearLayout tag

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="Quantity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:id="@+id/numbers">

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Order" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:id="@+id/numbers">
```

You're missing an `/` at the end of this tag.
Should be `android:id="@+id/numbers"/>`

Either that or close the tag properly with `</TextView>`.